# How to download the response file which is in zip format for a GET https request using Java. In postman the response is some junk character

Tags: java

I am using Java for this to create a connection `HttpURLConnection` but not sure how to download the response.

When I checked for the header fields from response, below are the details I found

> {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Server=[Apigee LB], Access-Control-Allow-Origin=[*], Access-Control-Allow-Methods=[GET, PUT, POST, DELETE], **Content-Disposition=[attachment; filename="OfflineQueryResult-2ba8631e-c542-49f0-9012-32875875d5f8.zip"]**, Connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[265], Access-Control-Max-Age=[3628800], Date=[Sun, 23 Aug 2020 10:15:42 GMT], Access-Control-Allow-Headers=[origin, x-requested-with, accept], Content-Type=[text/xml]}>

Here in the above object (higlighted), there is a filename inside the Content-Disposition, that filename I should be able to download automatically to the local folder or path

Can someone please help here

Comment: Read the Content-Disposition using [getHeaderField](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField(java.lang.String)).  For downloading, see the example in [the documentation of Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).

Comment: It looks like the content-type in the response header is not correct. It should be application/zip. This needs to be set correctly for the download to work in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using Java 11 or later, you don’t need HttpURLConnection at all.  You can use the [java.net.http](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html) package:

```
URL url = /* ... */;

Path downloadDir = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Downloads");

HttpResponse<Path> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(
    HttpRequest.newBuilder(url.toURI()).GET().build(),
    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFileDownload(downloadDir));

Path downloadedFile = response.body();
```

If you’re using a version of Java older than 11, you can obtain the disposition header using the [getHeaderField](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField(java.lang.String)) method.  And you can download using [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)).

```
HttpURLConnection conn = /* ... */;

Path downloadDir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Downloads");

Path downloadedFile = null;
String disposition = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
if (disposition != null) {
    String filenameIndex = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
    if (filenameIndex >= 0) {
        String filename = disposition.substring(filenameIndex + 9);
        if (filename.startsWith("\"")) {
            // filename is everything inside double-quotes.
            int endIndex = filename.indexOf('"', 1);
            filename = filename.substring(1, endIndex);
        } else {
            // filename is unquoted and goes until ';' or end of string.
            int endIndex = filename.indexOf(';');
            if (endIndex > 0 ) {
                filename = filename.substring(0, endIndex);
            }
        }
        downloadedFile = downloadDir.resolve(filename);
    }
}
if (downloadedFile == null) {
    downloadedFile = Files.createTempFile(downloadDir, null, null);
}

try (InputStream urlStream = conn.getInputStream()) {
    Files.copy(urlStream, downloadedFile,
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAX-RS Client API to consume the ZIP response :

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
InputStream is = client.target("http://host:port")
                       .path("api").path("API-Path")
                       .request().accept("application/zip")
                       .get(InputStream.class);

ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(is);
zis.getNextEntry();

// Print in console
Scanner sc = new Scanner(zis);
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: ... Assuming that @OP wants the first file in the zip file unzipped, and assuming that said file is a text file. AND assuming the the text file uses default text encoding (i.e. is not in UTF-16)

Answer (score 0):

To download using HttpURLConnection, you use

```
HttpURLConnection myConnection = ...;
InputStream stream = myConnection.getInputStream();
```

Then you need to suck up all the bytes from the stream. Basically, you create a read buffer (byte), call read(byte[]) on the InputStream, and then dump those bytes into a larger buffer, possibly a ByteBuffer object, until there is nothing left to read (read returns -1). Also, you can plug in [DataFetcher](https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java) to do the above for you